# Converting Ubuntu-Minimal 22.04 cloud image from .img file to VirtualBox .vdi disk image

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, qemu, ubuntu-minimal

I'm trying to use [Ubuntu-Minimal 22.04 pre-built cloud image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/jammy/release/) in VirtualBox. I've dowloaded .img file which (according to `file` util) has `QEMU QCOW2 Image (v2)` so I'm trying to convert it using `qemu-img` tool:

```
qemu-img convert -O vdi ubuntu-22.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img disk.vdi
```

It is being converted sussessfully, but when I attach converted disk image to VBox VM and try to start VM it fails with message "`GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID set, attempting initrdless boot`".

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. The same image as the KVM guest gives the same output. That's a console output. That doesn't mean the OS isn't booting.